# changing fragment in list view

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I want to stay in the same activity(it is a tabbed activity but I just want to change the fragment of the tab I am in when I press on a list item
So what should I do ?
pls help

public class PrayersAdvantagesFragment extends ListFragment {

```
private String[] data;
private ArrayList<String[]> a7adith;
private StringsListAdapter stringsListAdapter;
private AlertDialog categoryDialogObject;
int i;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    a7adith = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
    data = intent.getStringArrayExtra(MainActivity.A7ADITH);

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        a7adith.add(new String[]{data[i],data[i+1]});
        i++;
    }

    stringsListAdapter = new StringsListAdapter(getActivity(), a7adith);
    setListAdapter(stringsListAdapter);

    //registerForContextMenu(getListView());
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String[] string = (String[]) getListAdapter().getItem(position);



    BuildCategoryDialog(string);

    categoryDialogObject.show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set event to change fragment in **getView** method of StringListAdapter.
Hope this help you.